# Should we be concerned about the size of the node_modules folder in a nativescript shared codebase?

Tags: webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I realize this may be a "NOOB" moment, but I've looked down the `webpack.config.js` and didn't see anything obvious that answered this question.  That being said I'll be the first to admit I've taken the built-in webpack tools for granted and never really learned it.

Do we need to be concerned about the size of our APK or our Angular app due to the fact that our `node_modules` folder contains both nativescript plugins as well as web?

EX: `node_modules` contains both `nativescript-ui-chart` for nativescript, and `ngx-charts` for web.

Is the webpack AOT compiler (by using `ng build --prod` or `tns run android --bundle`) already taking care of that?  If not, is there something we can do or is that just an artifact of using a shared code base?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webpack will only bundle the `node_modules` / scripts those are required for the project irrespective of what you have in your `package.json`. So you don't have to worry about the size or what you have inside `node_modules` folder.

Webpack can be even explicitly configured to pickup or ignore particular package / scripts, learn more from the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts).